# Two forms submit with one button struts2

Tags: struts2

I am developing an astrology website, in which there are two forms , two forms are for male and female.

Both male and female enter their date of birth details as name, date of birth, time of birth and place of birth. I have a simple pojo class with the fields as mentioned. I can able to save single form details.

I am not getting any idea how to store two forms information on one click.

Comment: Why are you having two forms/ why can't you do it single form?

Comment: do you want that data to submit to same action with same method or different actions? you can do that even with simple JS like `document.getElementById("firstform").submit();` and `document.getElementById("firstform").submit();`. But i am not sure why you want to submit two forms as it seems that you need data of both in single action

Comment: Two `firstform`s ? :o)

Comment: @AndreaLigios: just a typo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript or jQuery to submit your forms. But first you should always look at combining the content of both the forms into 1.